# Java Elasticsearch - Boolquery with exists condition

Tags: java, api, elasticsearch, post

I have the following code, that I need to get not null results in some fields, and check values in anothers. (I'm using 'RestHighLevelClient')

But I got this error:

> Caused by: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]
>
> ....
>
> Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST],
>   host [http://192.168.8.101:9200], URI
>   [/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&scroll=1m&sear
>   .....
>
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[exists]
>   query does not support [boost]

Code:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("usuarioIntegracao"));
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tabela", "Arquivo", "Mensagem"));
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("statusTexto", "Erro"));
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("dataEntrada")
                            .from("now-1d/d")
                            .timeZone("-03:00"));

searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
searchSourceBuilder.size(9999);
searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

SearchResponse response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

And I have success searching the same on Postman:

```
{
    "size" : 1000,

    "sort" : [
        {"dataEntrada" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ],

    "query" : {
        "bool":{
          "must":[
            {"terms":{ "tabela" : ["Arquivo", "Mensagem"] }},

            {"term":{ "statusTexto" : "Erro" }},

            {"exists" : { "field" : "usuarioIntegracao" }},

            {"range" : {
                "dataEntrada" : {
                    "gte" : "now-1d/d",
                    "lt" :  "now/d",
                    "timeZone" : "-03:00"
                }
            }}
          ],
          "should":{},
          "must_not":{

          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is the syntax.
Try this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("usuarioIntegracao"))
    .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tabela", "Arquivo", "Mensagem"))
    .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("statusTexto", "Erro"))
    .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("dataEntrada").from("now-1d/d").timeZone("-03:00"));

searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQuery);
```